# Kendo UI Button and Popup

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, popupwindow

I need to add button "NEXT" in the pop up and how to trigger when I clicked button "NEXT" it will produce popup 2? Anyone know about it? Please refer my DEMO below. Thank you.

[DEMO HERE](https://dojo.telerik.com/aXUcUJOy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your element

```
 $('<label class="k-checkbox-label" for="' + guid + '">​</label>
<button id="button" class="k-button k-primary" type="button">Next</button>').appendTo(container);
```

and create a function to open the popup 2

```
$("#button").kendoButton({
        click: function(e) {                
            var dialog = $('#popup2');
            dialog.data("kendoDialog").open();
        }
});
```